# PowerShell using Test-Path to compare part of a filename

Tags: powershell

I am trying to compare 2 files in different folders but i need to use the first 8 Characters of the filename. below is what i have tried but i am not having any joy

```
$Source = "Path To PDF Files"
$Compare = "Path To PDF Files i Want To Comapare" 

GCI $Source | ForEach-Object{

if(Test-Path "$Compare\$($_.Name.Substring(0,8))") {

Move-Item $Compare\$($_.Name) "\\Destination\" 

    }
 }
```

Comment: Is the value of $Compare\$($_.Name.Substring(0,8)) what you expect ? Does that path exist ?

Comment: the path works when using $Compare\$($_.Name) but when i add the `.Substring `it does nothing. i thought by adding `.Substring `it would look at the first 8 Characters on both files.

Comment: But adding substring means you're truncating the path so the path is invalid, which is why Test-Path fails. Why do you you need the first 8 characters ?

Comment: that makes sense, the reason behind this is some files come back from our cloud with the (1) at the end of the file name due to them being opened more than once, because we have a unique code at the beginning  the files can still be moved regardless (if this makes sense haha)

Comment: write some code to check for that trailing `(#)` and remove it if found. THEN use that for your test. [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey if you could mark me up that would be nice as i am trying to build my Stack account up. thanks again

Comment: @RedecIndustrial -  sure ... plus, you can get rep points by working thru the Tour page for this site. [*grin*]

Comment: That's fantastic, I didn't know that thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after @Lee_Dailey pointed me in the right direction i changed the way i went about it below is the code snippet i wrote to get around the problem.

this will look for the number added to the end of a file and remove it for example

`file(1).pdf` it will remove the (1)

```
$SignedNt = GCI "PATH TO FILES" -Filter *.pdf 
$Pattern = "[(#)]"
ForEach($Sign in $SignedNt){
    if($Sign -match $Pattern){
    Rename-Item -Path $Sign.FullName -NewName (($Sign.Name)-replace '\([0-9]\)' , '') 

    }
}
```

once this cleans the file it then runs the code below compare and move it which in turn answers my question.

```
$Source = "Path To PDF Files"
$Compare = "Path To PDF Files i Want To Compare" 

GCI $Source | ForEach-Object{

if(Test-Path "$Compare\$($_.Name)") {

Move-Item $Compare\$($_.Name) "\\Destination\" 

    }
 }
```

hope this helps the next person